# Contracting a stress tensor

Tags: tensor-calculus, stress-strain

I'm reading [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251427701_Impulse_Response_of_a_Maxwell_Earth), and they go from equation (3):

$$
\left(s+\frac{\mu}{\nu}\right) \bar{\tau}_{k l}-\frac{1}{3} \frac{\mu}{\nu} \bar{\tau}_{k k} \delta_{k l}=2 \mu s \bar{e}_{k l}+\lambda s e_{k l} \delta_{k l}
$$

To equation (4):

$$
\bar{\tau}_{k k}=(3 \lambda+2 \mu) \bar{e}_{k k}
$$

By "contracting the stress tensor". I'm not sure exactly how they did it, if someone can explain the steps to go from (3) to (4) it would be great. I know that contracting means summing over identical indices, but it doesn't produce equation (4).

What I get by trying to contract:

$$
\bar{\tau}_{k k}\left(s+\frac{\mu}{\nu}-\frac{1}{3} \frac{\mu}{\nu}\right) = \bar{e}_{k k} s (2\mu + \lambda)
$$

Then:

$$
\bar{\tau}_{k k} = \bar{e}_{k k} s \left( \frac{2\mu+\lambda}{s+ \frac{2}{3}\frac{\mu}{\nu}} \right)
$$

So clearly I'm missing something

Comment: In more usual notation, the equation is $$
\left(s+\frac{\mu}{\nu}\right) \bar{\tau}_{k l}-\frac{1}{3} \frac{\mu}{\nu} \bar{\tau}_{m m} \delta_{k l}=2 \mu s \bar{e}_{k l}+\lambda s e_{m m} \delta_{k l}
$$ Try contracting that.

Comment: @Ghoster , I edited my attempt. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong there.

Comment: $\delta_{kk}$ is 3, not 1. Repeated indices are summed over.

Comment: What is s in these equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of a dirty scan, there’s a $t$ that should be an $l$ in your expression (addressed in an edit to the question). You also have a $kl$ index that reads $kk$ in the paper.

Assume equitriaxial stress and strain states, and assume that one $\epsilon_{kl}$ is missing a tilde (Laplace-domain function) as a typo in the original paper. Then, by the summation convention you mention,

$$
\left(s+\frac{\mu}{\nu}\right) \tilde{\tau}_{k l}- \frac{1}{3}\frac{\mu}{\nu} \tilde{\tau}_{kk} \delta_{k l}=2 \mu s \tilde{e}_{k l}+\lambda s \tilde{e}_{kk} \delta_{k l};
$$

$$
\left(s+\frac{\mu}{\nu}\right) \tilde{\tau}_{k l}- \frac{1}{3}\frac{\mu}{\nu} (\tilde{\tau}_{11}+\tilde{\tau}_{22}+\tilde{\tau}_{33}) \delta_{k l}=2 \mu s \tilde{e}_{k l}+\lambda s (\tilde{e}_{11}+\tilde{e}_{22}+\tilde{e}_{33}) \delta_{k l}.
$$

Now, for any given $k$, take $l=k$ so the Kronecker deltas $\delta_{lk}$ are 1, and sum the resulting expressions for all three values of $k$ to to retrieve the desired expression:

$$\tilde{\tau}_{11}=(3 \lambda+2 \mu) \tilde{e}_{11};$$
$$\tilde{\tau}_{22}=(3 \lambda+2 \mu) \tilde{e}_{22};$$
$$\tilde{\tau}_{33}=(3 \lambda+2 \mu) \tilde{e}_{33};$$
$$\tilde{\tau}_{kk}=(3 \lambda+2 \mu) \tilde{e}_{kk}.$$

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain what happened to the 1/3 factor and why there is a 3 in the last term? Seems like I still missing some steps

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify.